# TFS (On-premises) - Deploy: Windows Machine File Copy

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

My question is - to copy files to remote machines from the Drop folder, do I need that remote machine registered as an agent?

My remote machine is in the same network but still, I'm getting an ERROR to copy files.

Comment: Could you please post what error you are getting?

Comment: ERROR is " System error 1326 has occurred."

Comment: I found posts showing It may be an error with credentials. But I've configured it with Administrator's credentials.

Comment: Are you running this task in deployment group phase?

Comment: No Ankush ! Running it as a separate task with the separate machine.

Comment: No...I mean this task comes under which phase - Agent Phase or Deployment Group Phase? one more question - is your build agent also in the same network or you are using hosted agent?

Comment: Running with the Agent phase. My build agent is on the same network and not Microsoft hosted.

Comment: If agent is installed in the same network, then logon to that agent machine & try to connect with the remote machine from there using RDP with the same credentials. I think, you will also not able to connect with remote machine from there as well. Give it a  try.

Comment: It's Coming Ankush :(

Comment: Try adding domain-name in the username as per this link - https://superuser.com/questions/586110/whats-wrong-with-this-net-use-command#answer-586117

Comment: at least new error is coming now - system error 53 has occurred

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180851/discussion-between-ankush-jain-and-darshana-patel).

Comment: Yeah..lets discuss there..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not required to have a TFS Agent on the target server in order to copy files over to it, but you do need to have permission to write to it.  See the screenshot of what I did. Notice that I am storing the credentials as variables in the build definition.  The password is "locked" so no one can see the clear text password.  I have the Build Agent running under the same service account that has Admin privileges on the target server, but leaving them off did not help.  To test this out, try to log into the build server via RDP and then try to open file explorer and connect to the Target Server using the network path (\SomeServer\C$\SomePath\dir) and using the credentails (domain\login or just login) and see if it works, along with the password.

[image]

Comment: One concern was there for Domain. My system domain name is showing like "domainname.com" and AdminUser Domain Name is different like "DN".   This started working but I am still confused with how this is going.

Comment: The TFS instance, build server, and target server are all on the same domain, so I did not need to specify the domain name anywhere.  If it is finally working, then great.